# How to add and remove item in MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> and notify the UI in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I want to add and remove items in MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>. Adding items to the list is working fine and UI is also updating. But removal from array list is not working properly.

```
@HiltViewModel
class SecondViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private var _languagesList : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
    val languagesList : LiveData<ArrayList<String>> get() = _languagesList

    fun addInList() {
        val a = arrayListOf<String>()
        a.add("c++")
        _languagesList.postValue(a)
    }

    fun removeFromList() {
        _languagesList.value?.removeAt(0);
        //How to notify UI here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a simple solution if you want remove a selected item too

```
 fun addInList() {
    val oldList = _listChips.value.orEmpty()
    _listChips.value = ArrayList(oldList).apply {
        add("c++")
    }
    val oldList = ArrayList(_languagesList.value.orEmpty())
    oldList.add("C++")
    _languagesList.value = oldList
}

fun removeFromList() {
    val oldList = _listChips.value.orEmpty()
    _listChips.value =
        ArrayList(oldList.filterIndexed { index, _ -> index != oldList.indexOf("C++") })
}
```

Comment: this answer will work its just you have to observe that live data in UI thread and use notifyDataSetChanged with new data

Answer (score 1):

I have found a simple solution for array list.

```
fun addInList() {
    val oldList = ArrayList(_languagesList.value.orEmpty())
    oldList.add("C++")
    _languagesList.value = oldList
}

fun removeFromList() {
    val oldList = ArrayList(_languagesList.value.orEmpty())
    oldList.removeLast()
    _languagesList.value = oldList
}
```

Comment: Watch out. This won't work with ListAdapter, DiffUtil, or Compose State because you are reusing list instances.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addInList()` code shouldn't work either because it creates a new list each time, losing all the previous items in the list.

It is error prone to use a mutable List like ArrayList as your data type. It would be better to use read-only lists, which you could do like this:

```
private var _languagesList : MutableLiveData<List<String>> = MutableLiveData()
val languagesList : LiveData<List<String>> get() = _languagesList

fun addInList() {
    val oldList = _languagesList.value.orEmpty()
    _languagesList.value = oldList + "c++" // this is creating a new list
}

fun removeFromList() {
    val oldList = _languagesList.value.orEmpty()
    _languagesList.value = oldList.drop(1) // create new list with first item removed
}
```

I'm using the `.value` setter instead of `postValue` since these functions are probably called synchronously from the main thread.

If you really need the type to be ArrayList (although I can't think of a reason why), then you would need to copy your values into a new ArrayList specifically like this:

```
private var _languagesList : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> = MutableLiveData()
val languagesList : LiveData<ArrayList<String>> get() = _languagesList

fun addInList() {
    val oldList = _languagesList.value.orEmpty()
    _languagesList.value = ArrayList(oldList).apply {
        add("c++")
    }
}

fun removeFromList() {
    val oldList = _languagesList.value.orEmpty()
    _languagesList.value = ArrayList(oldList.drop(1))
}
```